# I can't put my foreach Select Option in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, foreach

Hi can someone help me put my **foreach** result in my **JS add row function**.

I'm Using Codeigniter that will pass the data from controller to view.

So I have **SELECT** in **VIEW** that will give results of my foreach particulars in my **OPTIONS**.

```
<td class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>">
        <option value="">Select Particulars</option>

        <?php foreach ($particularsData as $particulars)
        {
        ?>

        // FOR EACH RESULTS INSIDE THE OPTIONS
        <option value="<?php echo $particulars['feetype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $particulars['feetype_name']; ?> </option>

        <?php 
        } 
        ?>
    </select>                     
</td>
```

So the the Modal Form **Select Option** will look like this.
[image]

Now let's move to my **Add Row Function** in my **JS** where if you click **Add Row Button** on the top right side it will add new identical rows.

```
function addPaymentRow()
{
var tableLength = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr").length;

var tableRow;
var arrayNumber;
var count;

if(tableLength > 0) {       
    tableRow = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").attr('id');
    arrayNumber = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").attr('class');
    count = tableRow.substring(3);  
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    arrayNumber = Number(arrayNumber) + 1;                  
} else {
    // no table row
    count = 1;
    arrayNumber = 0;

}

// I NEED HELP HERE, I CAN ADD ROWS with no foreach value just plain input type, HOW CAN I ADD VALUES HERE FROM FOR EACH                  
var tr = '<tr id="row'+count+'" class="'+arrayNumber+' appended-exp-row">'+                                 
    '<td class="form-group">'+
        '<select class="form-control" name="subparticulars['+count+']" id="subparticulars'+count+'">'+
        '<option value="">Select Particulars</option>'+
        '</select>'+                        
    '</td>'+

    '<td class="form-group">'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subpaymentbalance['+count+']" id="subpaymentbalance'+count+'"/>'+                        
    '</td>'+

    '<td class="form-group">'+          
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subpaymentamount['+count+']" id="subpaymentamount'+count+'" onkeyup="calculateTotalAmount()" placeholder="Payment Amount" />'+                                   
    '</td>'+

    '<td class="form-group">'+
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="removePaymentRow('+count+')">Remove</button>'+
    '</td>'+
'</tr>';

if(tableLength > 0) {                           
    $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").after(tr);
} else {                
    $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody").append(tr);
}               
}
```

The **result** of **added row** will look like this.[image]

Can someone help me **populate** my **options** in my **JS** coming from my **foreach** like in my **VIEW**.

Comment: you want same select after add?

Comment: Yes just same select with same populated options coming from my for each. It's just as I said same Identical rows when I click add row button. I just need help in populating my options in my JS add row function

Comment: have a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp

Comment: Can you help me apply it in my code?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/vfgarsrp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: 
`$('.particulars option').clone()` will give you all the options of your main select then you just need to append that to your newly created select.

```
<td class="form-group">
<select class="form-control particulars" name="subparticulars[<?php echo $x; ?>]" id="subparticulars<?php echo $x; ?>">
    <option value="">Select Particulars</option>

    <?php foreach ($particularsData as $particulars)
    {
    ?>

    // FOR EACH RESULTS INSIDE THE OPTIONS
    <option value="<?php echo $particulars['feetype_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $particulars['feetype_name']; ?> </option>

    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
```

```
 function addPaymentRow()
    {
        var tableLength = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr").length;

        var tableRow;
        var arrayNumber;
        var count;

        if (tableLength > 0) {
            tableRow = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").attr('id');
            arrayNumber = $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").attr('class');
            count = tableRow.substring(3);
            count = Number(count) + 1;
            arrayNumber = Number(arrayNumber) + 1;
        } else {
            // no table row
            count = 1;
            arrayNumber = 0;

        }

// I NEED HELP HERE, I CAN ADD ROWS with no foreach value just plain input type, HOW CAN I ADD VALUES HERE FROM FOR EACH                  
        var tr = '<tr id="row' + count + '" class="' + arrayNumber + ' appended-exp-row">' +
                '<td class="form-group">' +
                '<select class="form-control" name="subparticulars[' + count + ']" id="subparticulars' + count + '"></select>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="form-group">' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subpaymentbalance[' + count + ']" id="subpaymentbalance' + count + '"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="form-group">' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subpaymentamount[' + count + ']" id="subpaymentamount' + count + '" onkeyup="calculateTotalAmount()" placeholder="Payment Amount" />' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="form-group">' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="removePaymentRow(' + count + ')">Remove</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

        if (tableLength > 0) {
            $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody tr:last").after(tr);
        } else {
            $("#addSubPaymentTable tbody").append(tr);
        }

        $('.particulars option').clone().appendTo('#subparticulars' + count);
    }
```

Comment: It worked I just add slight adjusment since it doubles the Select Particulars when new row is added, I just remove the '<option value="">Select Particulars</option>' in the JS, thanks.

Comment: yes  right, clone ll give you all the option so you dont need to add that